# Hibernate Problem, a Map with an Object as a Key and an Integer as a Value

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, annotations

I'm trying to add a quantity functionality for items in my "shopping" app. I have an **Order** object, that has a **Map** that has keys which are **Case** objects (like a case for musical equipment), and the values which they keys store are **Integers**, that represent the quantity of those cases in that order.

Before,**Orders** had just a **List** of **Cases** in a @OneToMany relationship, and it worked fine, saved to DB without any problem (no quantity functionality). The **Order** and **Case** objects have tables, and are joined bi-directionally.

Now I wanted to add a **Join Table** that consisted of the Order_id, Case_id, and the quantity (of a case in an order). I've seen many examples but most have a simple key, and the value as object (opposite to what I have), and the key in most cases reffers to a parameter of the value (which is not my case).

At the moment I am recieving a org.hibernate.TransientObjectException, because I'm not saving the **Case** object. I'm probably not even mapping it correctly. I'm pretty lost as to how to use the annotations in my specific case. Here is the code:

**Order**

```
@Proxy(lazy=false)  // test
@Table(name="orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

//  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name="quantities",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
//      ,
//      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="case_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
        )
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="case", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @Column(name="quantity")
    private Map<Case, Integer> cases;

(...)
```

**Case**

```
@Proxy(lazy=false)
@Table(name="cases")
public class Case {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

(...)

    @ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, 
                        CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id")
    private Order order;
```

Comment: Try to use a composite key, which is some kind of extension of the Joint table, because in your case your relationship has an extra attribute (quantity) beside the foreign keys from the tables. See the composite key section here: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**Order**

```
@Proxy(lazy=false)  // test
@Table(name="orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="quantities",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="Order_id")}
        )
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="Case_id")
    @Column(name="quantity")
    private Map<Case, Integer> cases;

(...)
```

**Case**

```
@Proxy(lazy=false)
@Table(name="cases")
public class Case {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    (...)

    @ManyToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, 
                        CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name="quantities",
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
        ,
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="case_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
    )
    private List<Order> order;
```

Sources :

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyJoinColumn.html

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JPA/0320__JPA_ElementCollection_MapKeyEntity.htm

Comment: Still the same exception. I don't understand why the Case would have a List of Orders. I'm assuming most Cases will be unique objects (The client specifis their exact parameters), so a Case belongs to only one Order. I'll check out the sources you provided.

Comment: The solution from java2s seems like exactly my case, but it doesn't work. Still the same exception.